# How to convert object to array in dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

How to convert  object to array in dataweave and i can say i want to remove that curly braces from input

***Input:***

```
{    
  "Person": [    
    "sri",    
    "123456",    
    "India"    
  ]    
}
```

***Expected Output***

```
[
  "sri",
  "123456",
  "India" 
]
```

Comment: Could you please explain what kind of output is this? I.e. what is the meaning of `Person` sitting on its own like that?

Comment: Geroge i have a given examplle. dont see the this person as real :) what ii need iis need to remmove the curly braces from input

Comment: You can't , these curly braces identify an Object in JSON, assuming you are using JSON as your format.  If you do then this is not JSON

Comment: Yes i am using json format, ignore  the data inside {..}

Comment: curly braces identify an Object in JSON . Cant we convert this into array

Comment: What is the form of the array based upon your input?

Comment: Thanks george for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming a JSON output, it is not valid to have a key (ie `"Person":`) without being inside an object.

If you are only interested only in the contents of the array then you can use the DataWeave expression `payload.Person` which will return `["sri", "123456","India"]`, which is a valid array in JSON.